# How to filter by orderByChild containing a string in Firebase query-based rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to get all the users that are friends of the logged user. This is my data structure.

```
{
  "users": {
    "UID1":{
        "name":"Pepito",
        "friends":{
            "UID2":true,
            "UID4":true,
        }
     }
     ...
  }
}
```

I am getting the users with this code

```
Firebase.database.reference().child("users")
        .orderByChild("friends/" + Firebase.user.uid).equalTo(true)
```

And the rules should be

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users" : {
      ".read" : "query.orderByChild.contains('friends/')",
      "$uid" : {
            ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the rules not working, I am getting this error when I try to save

```
Error saving rules – Line 6: Invalid property access: target is not an object.
```

The line 6 is

```
".read" : "query.orderByChild.contains('friends/')",
```

I also tried with

```
".read" : "query.orderByChild == 'friends/'+auth.uid",
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this type of secure query is possible, but that last snippet looks what I'd use. What was the error/problem with that last rule?

Comment: In general I'd model the inverse collection too, so that you can just read `/users/peopleThatHaveFriendedMe`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: This is the error in the last one

    `Error saving rules – Line 6: Invalid == expression: right operand must be an ordering or string literal when comparing against an ordering.`  
  
I saw your answer in the other question, but I want to list in one query all the users, that's not possible with the structure that you recommend, with that structure I need to do a query to get the id of the users, and then one query per user, right?

Comment: Ok I found other of your answers that explains that this is a normal thing in firebase, and how the requests are done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786

Comment: Unfortunately the query you want to do simply isn't possible. You'll need to set up a structure that allows the query you want, so if you want to get the friends of the current user, you'll need to store that information in your data model.